# Firebase lagging with data updation - Multiplayer game

Tags: android, firebase, libgdx

I am using Firebase as my back-end database for multiplayer open world game.
I need write speed up to 100 millisecond to keep all player updated real time.
My game graphics remains smooth with LibGdx engine but then Firebase lags with writing data which shows opponent player to his delayed position.
I am using interface to communicate with core LibGdx game class to Android features (Since no Firebase in LibGdx).

Please suggest me to achieve smooth mechanism to update data and achieve smooth multiplayer approach with Firebase. (Including LibGdx)

Following code shows my Firebase snippet:

```
//For writing owners location update
taskMap.clear();
taskMap.put("x", Connect.carX);
taskMap.put("y", carY);
taskMap.put("angle", angle);
taskMap.put("rx", rx);
taskMap.put("ry", ry);
taskMap.put("fx", fx);
taskMap.put("fy", fy);
taskMap.put("wheelAngle", wheelAngle);
db.child("public").child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).updateChildren(taskMap);
taskMap.clear();
taskMap.put("damage", damage);
taskMap.put("gear", gear);
taskMap.put("fuel", fuel);
db.child(firebaseAuth.getUid()).updateChildren(taskMap);


//For reading opponent locations update
LibGdx.core.class.dummyCarUpdate(postSnapshot.getKey(),
Float.parseFloat(postSnapshot.child("x").getValue().toString()),
Float.parseFloat(postSnapshot.child("y").getValue().toString()),
Float.parseFloat(postSnapshot.child("angle").getValue().toString()),
Float.parseFloat(postSnapshot.child("rx").getValue().toString()),
Float.parseFloat(postSnapshot.child("ry").getValue().toString()),
Float.parseFloat(postSnapshot.child("fx").getValue().toString()),
Float.parseFloat(postSnapshot.child("fy").getValue().toString()),
Float.parseFloat(postSnapshot.child("wheelAngle").getValue().toString()));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The technique you are looking for is called Interpolation. This technique allows you to smoothen the resulting movement on clients connected to your database.
[Learn a bit about interpolation here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3nsq3s9jxys)

You will need to store previous data to interpolate with new data. Also you will decide how fast the interpolation is gonna take between states.

Comment: Thanks, I used the same method to cure my problem. Now updating data to Firebase with 300 millisecond intervals and smoothing out with Interpolation. And believe me all works smooth.